# C++ Fizzbuzz Leetcode vector push_back() replacing all previous elements

Tags: c++, vector, push-back, fizzbuzz

I am having an issue where the C++ push_back() function is replacing all previous elements in a vector. Code that works is given

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<string> fizzBuzz(int n) {
        vector<string> ans;
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            if(i%3==0 && i%5==0)
                ans.push_back("FizzBuzz");
            else if(i%3==0)
                ans.push_back("Fizz");
            else if(i%5==0)
                ans.push_back("Buzz");
            else
                ans.push_back(to_string(i));
        }
        return ans;
    }
};
```

will output

```
["1","2","Fizz","4","Buzz","Fizz","7","8","Fizz","Buzz","11","Fizz","13","14","FizzBuzz"]
```

meanwhile my code

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<string> fizzBuzz(int n) {
        vector<string> os;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            if (n % 15 == 0) 
                os.push_back("FizzBuzz");
            else if (n % 3 == 0) 
                os.push_back("Fizz");
            else if (n % 5 == 0) 
                os.push_back("Buzz");
            else 
                os.push_back(to_string(i));
        }
        return os;
    }
};
```

will output

```
["FizzBuzz","FizzBuzz","FizzBuzz","FizzBuzz","FizzBuzz","FizzBuzz","FizzBuzz","FizzBuzz","FizzBuzz","FizzBuzz","FizzBuzz","FizzBuzz","FizzBuzz","FizzBuzz","FizzBuzz"]
```

If the testcase is 3 it will be `["Fizz", "Fizz", "Fizz"]` or if the testcase if 4 it will be `["1", "2", "3", "4"]`

Essentially the last value replaces all previous elements with that specific answer.

Given that my code and the answer code is almost exactly the same (except my vector is named `ok` and the answer vector is named `ans`, why is my code causing an issue with `push_back()`?

Comment: Did you maybe want to use `i` instead of `n` for your math? `if (i % 15 == 0)`, etc.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thank you! I see what I did wrong now (Whenever I was first solving the question I was thinking of fizzbuzz (int n) is as single run, not a loop until n, so I had n as the if/else param.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is correct, but when you are using if and else if  you are giving conditions on 'n' instead of 'i'.Try changing them, you will get the correct answer.

```
vector<string> fizzBuzz(int n) {
      vector<string> os;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            if (i %15==0 ) {
                os.push_back("FizzBuzz");}
            else if (i % 3 == 0) {
                os.push_back("Fizz");}
            else if (i % 5 == 0) {
                os.push_back("Buzz");}
            else 
                {os.push_back(to_string(i));}
        }
        return os;
    }
};
```